# Time complexity of a Function in c++

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o

What will be the time complexity for this function, can someone explain?

```
void fun(int n) { 
  int i,j,k, count = 0;
  for(i = n/2; i <= n; i++) 
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j = 2*j)
      for(k = 1; k <= n; k++) 
        count++;
}
```

I am trying to find the time complexity for the given function. I think that second loop is O(n) but some said that it is O(log(n)).

Comment: Since the number of operations is reflected in `count`, why don't you just return that value and then plot it against `n`?

Comment: C++ has nothing to do with complexity, it is a generic concept.  Multiply how each loop depends on n and multiply. So something like (n/2)*(log(n))*n which will be (n^2)(log(n))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop will perform `n/2` iterations. On each of its iterations
the middle loop will perform `log(n)` iterations, since on every step j gets multiplied by factor of 2.
On each of its iterations the inner loop will perform `n` steps.

So complexity is `O(n/2 * log(n) * n) = O(n^2 * log(n))`.

Comment: Or the compiler might optimize it to a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop (i) has a complexity of O(n/2)

The middl-er loop (j) has a complexity of O(log(n))

The inner loop (k) has a complexity of O(n)

Has they are nested, the total complexity of the function in term of n is

`(n/2) * log(n) * n = n² * log(sqrt(n))`
which asymptotically, taking into account big-O notation gives `O(n² * log(n))`

Comment: log(n) / 2 is the same as log(sqrt(n)). However, as another answer pointed out, asymptotically O(log(sqrt(n)) is the same as O(log(n)).